# big O for an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I have a question about this algorithm, I am having hard time in understanding the complexity

```
    While(input) {
            ...
            array to check 
            ...
           for (int i=0; i< arraysize; i++) {  
                creation first subarray; 
                creation second subarray; 
           } 

           for (int i=0; i < firstsubarraysize; i++) {
                 addinput to array;
                for( int j = 0; j < secondsubarraysize; j++) {
                   calculate array[j] * input;
             }
           }
   }// endwhile
```

So, considering input a M variable and the array is N, the big O would be O(m(nlogn)) or O(n2)? 
The sub arrays are not always n\2. 
I apologize If I'm not very clear.

Comment: What does "creation first subarray" do? We can't analyze the runtime without knowing this.

Comment: It creates a subarray with all numbers close to input (10 numbers before and after input). The second array is other numbers. That for is used to discard numbers that are not used. So both sub arrays are always smaller than the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, for each nested loop, you will have one N in the big O for time complexity.

Here assume the outer most loop `while` run M times, then there are two nested `for` inside of it. So the total is `O(M N^2)`.

Comment: So, it does not matter if the two nested loops are running in less than N times (they are sub arrays always smaller than the original)?

Comment: Important to keep in mind that big O targets the worst scenario, so if it can be worse, it is.

Comment: OK, thank you. I thought it was n log n because of the sub arrays.

Comment: @JamX well, it could be n log n if there was more details about sub arrays suggesting that this a log based complexity. Otherwise, I assume that N times is a possibility.

Comment: The subarrays are 1) numbers close to input 2) numbers very smaller than input. There are always numbers discarded from the first array, building the sub arrays. The original array is not in order.

Comment: it is hard to guess in your case. but if the elements are not sorted, i would assume it is not log N

Comment: @CSPei The elements are not sorted in the original array. Thank you anyways, I know it's a bit unusual.